# Hide "Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)" in less +F

Tags: less

When running less +F *filename* there is a "bar" in the bottom with the text "Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)".

Is there a way to hide this text while remaining in follow-mode?

Comment: There's no easy way to remove this message aside from patching and recompiling less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try patching the string *Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)* in your own copy of the binary file `/usr/bin/less`, if you can find that string. For example,

```bsh
fgrep -abo 'Waiting for data... (interrupt to abort)' /usr/bin/less
```

should print the offset in bytes to the string. But it shows nothing (in my version of `less`) because it seems the message is in 2 parts. For example, this works:

```
$ fgrep -abo 'Waiting for data' /usr/bin/less
125920:Waiting for data
$ fgrep -abo '... (interrupt to abort)' /usr/bin/less
163488:... (interrupt to abort)
```

So you need to suppress the 2 strings. (This means you will also never see *... (interrupt to abort)* in other circumstances.)

You can suppress a string by replacing the first character by a null, provided the program is using typical library calls to print them. For example, with this script:

```
cp /usr/bin/less myless
chmod +x myless
zap(){
 offset=$(fgrep -abo "$1" myless)      # eg 125920:Waiting for data
 offset=${offset%:*}              # remove :....
 printf '\x00'  |
 dd bs=1 count=1 status=none conv=notrunc seek="$offset" of=myless
}
zap 'Waiting for data'
zap '... (interrupt to abort)'
cmp -l /usr/bin/less myless       # check only 2 differences
./myless +F /var/log/messages
```

Comment: I'm impressed. I wish there was a simple flag to omit the "status bar" however.

Comment: @ggwpp Write a patch, offer to merge it.